# How can I build an array of all possible permutations in PHP from 4 distinct 'scenarios'?

Tags: php, algorithm, permutation

I'm trying to build a php script that, for a given number of cats and collars, builds an array of  all possible permutations.

For example:

I have 4 different collars: `A, B, C and D.` If I have 1 cat, I have 4 possible permutations - they can be wearing collar A, B, C or D.

It turns out that the number of possible permutations is:

```
4n
```

Thus if I have 2 cats I have 16 possible permutations, 3 cats 64 permutations etc.

So, if I have the following code:

```
$collars = array('yellow','blue','green','pink');
$cats = array('bob','frank');
$no_cats = count($cats);
```

How can I get it to generate an array of these permutations?

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [bob] => yellow,
      [frank] => yellow
    )
  [1] => Array
   (
      [bob] => yellow,
      [frank] => blue
   )
  
 [...]
  
  [15] => Array
   (
      [bob] => pink,
      [frank] => pink
   )
 )
```

Here's where I've got to (I know it's wrong not least because the number of collar loops is hardcoded to the number of cats):

```
$collars = array('yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'pink');
$cats = array('bob', 'frank');
$i = 0;

foreach ($collars as $collar_a){
    foreach ($collars as $collar_b){
        foreach ($cats as $cat){
            $output[$i][$cat] = $collar_a;
            $output[$i][$cat] = $collar_b;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

This generates:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bob] => yellow
            [frank] => yellow
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bob] => blue
            [frank] => blue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [bob] => green
            [frank] => green
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [bob] => pink
            [frank] => pink
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [bob] => yellow
            [frank] => yellow
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [bob] => blue
            [frank] => blue
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [bob] => green
            [frank] => green
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [bob] => pink
            [frank] => pink
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [bob] => yellow
            [frank] => yellow
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [bob] => blue
            [frank] => blue
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [bob] => green
            [frank] => green
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [bob] => pink
            [frank] => pink
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [bob] => yellow
            [frank] => yellow
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [bob] => blue
            [frank] => blue
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [bob] => green
            [frank] => green
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [bob] => pink
            [frank] => pink
        )

)
```

It has the right number of loops but clearly not the right permutations. I suspect this can easily be solved by a self-referencing function but they're above my skill-level.

Any help would be *enormously* appreciated as I've been pulling my hair out over this for 2 days now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will require 3 nested loops for this.

- First outer loop to loop over all cats.
- Second outer loop to loop over all previously collected combination results for previous cats.
- Third inner loop to add current cat and collar combination to previously collected result.

The code below I believe is readable accordingly.

```
<?php

$collars = array('yellow','blue','green','pink');
$cats = array('bob','frank');

$result = [[]];
foreach($cats as $cat){
    $temp = [];
    foreach($result as $r){
        foreach($collars as $collar){
            $temp[] = array_merge($r, [ $cat => $collar]); 
        }
    }
    $result = $temp;
}


print_r($result);
```

---

Total combinations possible is not **4<sup>n</sup>** all the time.
Say, size of `cats` is `m` and size of collars is `n`.
So, total combinations possible is **n<sup>m</sup>**.